# Server error in '/' application ASP.NET when enter directly into URL browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013

Hi my friends i've been searching on this error for a long time but i dont find any answer...

Here is my Controller Code:

```
[HttpPost]
 public ActionResult TakePool_2(ModeloGeneralVD Modelo_KVD)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ModeloGeneralVD Modelo_Pool2 = new ModeloGeneralVD();
            kvd_dbEntities db = new kvd_dbEntities();
           // De Modelo_Pool1
            Modelo_Pool2.Nombre = Modelo_KVD.Nombre;
            Modelo_Pool2.Apellido = Modelo_KVD.Apellido;
            Modelo_Pool2.Cedula = Modelo_KVD.Cedula;
            Modelo_Pool2.Codigo_Operador = Modelo_KVD.Codigo_Operador;
            Modelo_Pool2.Cod_Compartel = Modelo_Pool2.ObtenerCodCompartel(Modelo_KVD.Codigo_Operador);

            var Lista = Modelo_Pool2.ObtenerDataKVDMaster(Modelo_Pool2.Cod_Compartel);
            Modelo_Pool2.Tipo_KVD = Lista.Type;
            Modelo_Pool2.Departamento = Lista.DeparmentName;
            Modelo_Pool2.Municipio = Lista.MunicipalityName;
            Modelo_Pool2.Centro_Poblado = Lista.VillageName;

            var Lista2 = Modelo_Pool2.ObtenerDataInstallation(Modelo_Pool2.Cod_Compartel);
            Modelo_Pool2.DANE_Departamento = Lista2.DepartmentCode;
            Modelo_Pool2.DANE_Municipio = Lista2.MunicipalityCode;
            Modelo_Pool2.DANE_Centro_Poblado = Lista2.VillageCode;

            List<SelectListItem> ListaTipoDocumento = new List<SelectListItem>();
            ListaTipoDocumento.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Cédula de Ciudadanía", Value = "1", Selected = true });
            ListaTipoDocumento.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Tarjeta de Identidad", Value = "2"});
            ListaTipoDocumento.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "No Registra", Value = "3" });
            ViewBag.Lista_TipoDocumento = ListaTipoDocumento;

            List<SelectListItem> ListaSexo = new List<SelectListItem>();
            ListaSexo.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Hombre", Value = "1", Selected = true });
            ListaSexo.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Mujer", Value = "2" });
            ViewBag.Lista_Sexo = ListaSexo;

            List<SelectListItem> Lista_Periocidad = new List<SelectListItem>();
            Lista_Periocidad.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Diario", Value = "1", Selected = true });
            Lista_Periocidad.Add(new SelectListItem{Text = "Semanal",Value = "2"});
            Lista_Periocidad.Add(new SelectListItem{Text = "Mensual",Value = "3"});
            Lista_Periocidad.Add(new SelectListItem{Text = "No Registra",Value = "3"});
            ViewBag.Lista_Periocidad = Lista_Periocidad;
            return View(Modelo_Pool2);
        }
    //Hubo un error en el modelo de datos, regresar:
        return View(Modelo_KVD);
    }
```

When I start the project from the initial page and i charge data and move to the second page (TakePool_2) no errors.

But when I enter the URL directly into the browser (/Pool/TakePool_2) gives me an error:

"server error in '/' application. the resource cannot be found"

I guess that is because I am not passing data into the model to the controller .. 
How I can prevent this from happening?

Comment: You have it set as Post only with a `HttpPostAttribute`... You're not going to be able to see it by using a Get request in your browser.

Comment: @RobH: You can post directly as answer when you have it, even if it's a short one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your action method is expecting a POST request:

```
[HttpPost]
```

When you manually enter a URL into the browser and navigate to that URL, you're issuing a GET request.  You either need to issue a POST request or remove the method attribute which requires a POST request.  (Or create a second method to handle GET requests.)

Browsers don't usually have an option to manually issue a POST request, but you can do so with browser debugging tools or with plugins like RESTClient for Firefox.

Comment: I put this: [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult TakePool_2()
        {
            return RedirectToAction("TakePool_1", "Pool");
        }

Comment: @AliBriceño: That seems like a pretty strange workaround.  Why not just remove the `[HttpPost]` attribute and let that one method handle both GET and POST requests?  Renaming your actions like that makes the URLs less readable (less RESTful) and the redirect results in two requests instead of just one.

Comment: So... what for the header '[HttpPost]' is placed?

Comment: @AliBriceño: That's there to tell the MVC routing engine that this particular action method is only to be used for POST actions.

Answer (score 0):

There are several http VERBS. For your problem we need to differ between GET and POST.

You do fire a GET Request if you visit a page. When you fire up your application, you use a GET request for your initial page, then you click a button or link and call your method `TakePool_2`, which is marked as a `[HttpPost]`. So you are sending data to your application.

The application does something with it and then returns a view.

It does not work per direct access, because your application expects a POST but you are issung a GET request.

Comment: Thanks Serv, its like David says... both of you have right... thanks a lot!